# Remember Me in asp:login control is not working properly with FBA authentication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication, login

I have created a custom login page for FBA and using asp:login control for login purpose. When I am deselecting the "Remember Me" checkbox then also it's is creating "FedAuth" cookie for that which should not be created as I don't want create the persistent cookie at that time.

Can you please let me know any solution for this. It works fine if I login to the site using Remember me checked.

Thanks in advance.

-Ankit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the following thread for the answer to your question: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/et-EE/sharepoint2010programming/thread/06ec9060-4b98-412c-b6d5-7a7139b36839

Hope this helps,

Raphael.